# How to select data from arrayList

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I'm new to android. And I have an issue (noob question), could you help?

I have a database method getAllQuests() to fetch all records from the table into ArrayList. The code is below. I assume it works.

Next step is to fetch specific data from ArrayList. Question is: how to do this?
I assume i could use indexOf() or get(). But still i don't get how to fetch a proper row. The output is below.

So i need to put 1 row from a table into ArrayList? Or I need to use another approach?

```
// Getting All Quests
public List<Quest> getAllQuests() {
    List<Quest> questList = new ArrayList<Quest>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Quest quest = new Quest();
            quest.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            quest.setQuestName(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setQuestPlayer(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setStatus(cursor.getInt(3));

            // Adding quest to list
            questList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return quest list
    return questList;
}


// I try to figure out what to do
List<Quest> questList = db.getAllQuests();
int index = questList.indexOf(1);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- index of Quest= " + index);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- element of " + index + " is " + questList.get(1));
```

The output of that code is:

```
10-20 08:39:30.210  D/myLogs: --- index of Quest= -1

10-20 08:39:30.210  D/myLogs: --- element of -1 is com.homemade.saga.Quest@41b10288
```

Comment: You could try to iterate over that array using enhanced for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through a list of objects using the **for each** construct

```
for (Quest q: questlist) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"--- index of Quest= " + String.valueOf(q.getIndex));
    ...... etc
}
```

- Note this assumes the **getIndex** *getter* method has been setup in the Quest class.

Comment: Thank you! I learned more about ArrayLists and all works just fine!